# How to install wifi in Kali Linux single boot?

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I have installed Kali Linux as single boot in Dell Inspiron and I am unable to use wifi. I have no internet connection to Kali Linux so apt etc will not work.

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0781:5581 SanDisk Corp. Ultra
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc. MK260 Wireless Combo Receiver
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Sometimes `iwlwifi` driver is not installed during OS installation.

Comment: If you're new to Linux systems in general please do not use Kali. It does things very differently to the standard distributions because it's not intended for everyday general use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your specific Dell Inspiron model has an Intel Wi-Fi chip, its driver is most likely named `iwlwifi`, as @P_Yadav guessed in the comments.

The `iwlwifi` driver probably is already installed, as it is included in the standard Linux kernel. But the firmware package it needs to run might not be.

It looks like the name of the package should be `firmware-iwlwifi` in the package group named `firmware-nonfree`. Use the package manager tool to install this package from the Kali installation media, if possible.

(The `-nonfree` here does **not** mean you need to pay for it; it basically just means you don't get the source code for it, so it's not Free Software.)

You probably have a CD or a USB stick you used to install Kali in the first place. Unless you explicitly selected "install everything", there is more packages on the installation media than was installed on your laptop by default. See if you can find a file named like `firmware-iwlwifi*.deb` in there. If you find it, double-click it or run `dpkg -i  <insert full pathname here>/firmware-iwlwifi*.deb` as root to install it. Then reboot.

Or you could use a second computer with a working internet connection to download the package from [Kali package repository](http://http.kali.org/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/), put it onto a USB stick and move it to your system that way.

Comment: i don't have internet connection to kali linux then how can I install these packages

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for your help i downloaded the package from repository and installed it with dpkg but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: hey telcoM do you have any other way

Comment: Please edit your question to add all the error messages you might have seen, and also **all messages from Linux system logs that seem related to WiFi**. Also please use the `lspci -nn` and/or `lsusb` commands to identify the exact model of your WiFi adapter: "Dell Inspiron" is a whole line of customizable laptops, with a huge range of models. Without knowing the exact model, we can only guess which WiFi adapter it might have.

Comment: i have edited my question. take a look

Comment: There does not seem to be any WiFi device visible. The Logitech MK260 is a dedicated keyboard+mouse receiver. Please see if your laptop has a physical radio switch and if it has, ensure that it's switched on. Also check the BIOS settings: the WiFi chip might be disabled in the BIOS. If those don't solve the issue, then this might be a hardware problem. Are you sure it *has* WiFi in the first place? If you bought it used, the previous owner may have taken out the WiFi module for use in another system.

Comment: I can't boot into bios. Neither F2 nor F12 are working to boot into bios. You got an alternative?

Comment: one more thing now i have a temporary internet connection